# pgSql stored data manipulation/calculation script

Tags: postgresql

I would like to find the best way to execute stored script that would make calculation on provided data.
I would need to have this scripts stored as a list in a table.

For example

```
id|name|script
1|adition dataA.val1 to dataA.val2|var arrayResult; foreach(row in dataA) arrayResult.add(row.val1+row.val2); return arrayResult;
2|....
```

And then we would have generic function to execute script with a provided data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eg.evaluateScript(
    IN script text,
    IN dataA ???,
    IN dataB ???,
    IN dataC ???,
  RETURNS result AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN

    ... here we have a process to make data manipulation base on script applied to dataA, dataB and dataC ...

    RETURN result;
END;
$BODY$
```

Of course this script should be able to do only data calculation/manipulstion (no select on any table, insert, update or whatever pgSql action that have nothing to do with data manipulation)

Also I don't want to create stored procedure for each script.

Comment: What language do you want to write this embedded script in? plpgsql? Because I can't see how that would work without directly updating the source-code of an existing function. Would you be ok with a dynamic language like plperl or plpython etc?

Comment: Can be any language, this is for the moment to define. Python would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found the extension PL/V8, that is a Javascript engine. There I can use the js function eval to execute text source code.

```
create or replace function
js(src text, input json) returns json as $$
  var evalRes = eval(src + ' output;');
  return JSON.stringify(evalRes);
$$ LANGUAGE plv8;

select js('var a = input.test; var output = []; for(k in a) { output.push(10+a[k]); };', '{"test": [1,2,3]}'::json)
```